# Can you call a voicemail greeting a voicemail?

Tags: word-choice

I just wrote an email where I was sharing someone's voicemail greeting, but instead of referring to it as a voicemail greeting, I simply called it a voicemail.

> I called this number and it left a voice mail telling me to call his cell phone.

Am I using voicemail correctly here? Or should I have said "voice mail greeting" instead? The former came to mind automatically, so I wrote that in my email. But I realized after writing it that it could easily be confused with the voicemail you leave on someone's answering machine.

What would you call a voice mail greeting? Would you call it a  voice mail greeting, a voice mail, or an answering message? Are all three equally acceptable?

Comment: Voice mail greeting, it is. But it's okay if you already sent the mail.

Comment: Yes, a voicemail is what you leave on someone's answering machine. I'm not sure there is a nice and unambiguous word for the greeting. "Voicemail message" could easily refer to the voicemail you leave as well.

Comment: No, you can't. You seem to be asking whether the message offering you the facility of leaving a voicemail is itself a voicemail. Is that right?

*Message* or even *answer* might work…

Comment: I think informally referring to it as a 'voicemail' is pretty common. If you're writing more formally, 'voicemail message' is also great